# Preprocessing data to differentiate Input variables and sample data when using Keras to build a neural network

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am a beginner using Keras, I am trying to preprocess data for training in order to build a neural network. However, I was told that from the csv file where I am getting my data from, the first 6 columns are the x values while the rest are y values. How can I deal with this situation in order to split the data correctly for training and testing. The data is all numerical, it is not categorical. It will be used to predict movement.

Answer (score 0):

When splitting data into training and testing, you aren't splitting along the columns, you're splitting along the rows, so both the training and test sets will have identical columns, but different rows.

You can use scikit-learns `train_test_split` ([docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html)) to do this for you. So to create an 80-20 split you would do:

```
df = pd.read_csv(<path to csv>)

train, test = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.20, shuffle=True, random_state=42)
```

Note that in the docs the example splits the label column out too, however you don't need to do this if you wish to keep the labels and features together.

The `random_state` parameter (choose any number you like) just ensures that when you re-run the code, the split will be exactly the same (i.e. it is reproducible) each time.